# Load Adsense ads first, then page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, adsense

I am getting very low CPC and I am suspecting it is because of my ads taking a while to load. Is there anyway for me to load the ads first and then the page? I want to test this out because I've tried everything in order to optimize Adsense, but still for some reason I am getting very low CPC. Currently, the only option for us to use is Asynchronous ads. This will load the ads after the page has loaded, but I want to experiment on loading the ads before. Is there anyway to solve this problem so the ads load first and then the page?

Comment: loading ads before your normal content will make your viewers wait for the content to load which in turn is not what you want to be going for.

Comment: @honest_questions I know, but I'm trying to debug the problem of my very low CPC and RPM. I want to see if the ads taking a while to load is the cause of it.

Comment: @user2896120 how many total hits are you getting on your page? Loading the ads quicker won't help if nobody is seeing them anyway.

Comment: @Steve Yesterday, I received 30,000 page views, but my CPC was only $0.09 and RPM was $0.12. I only made $3 from those page views. All my traffic is from social media

Answer (score 1):

You could delay loading more of your page and/or remove the async attributes from the advertising scripts.

To delay loading of your content: use AJAX to load the actual content and wait till the ads have loaded before you load it. But this might well be afoul with the terms and conditions of Google. Be very careful.

To get the ads to load sooner: move the appropriate `<script>` tag to the `<head>` of the html and remove the `async` attribute.

As to the results: I'm pretty convinced you're going to make it worse, not better.

Comment: good answer. Informed him on what he could do to obtain the result and also warned him of his actions. Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

CPC is cost per click - see https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/32725?hl=en) and is set by the people buying the ads. If you were to increase this figure, you would need the advertisers to increase the price they pay. Without changing your content (to something advertisers would pay more for), there isn't much you can do.

A better approach to gain more money would be to get more viewers to click your ads. This can be done by getting more traffic (and you could even advertise yourself), or ensuring the ads are something that your viewers would like (I worked on a website some time ago where the ads Google were placing had nothing in common with the content of the site).

Comment: I like the information, though this doesn't address the OP's question. He is concerned that users are not clicking because the ads are not loading fast enough before they deviate to another part of the site or leave the site completely. He basically wants to know how to make the ads load first for debugging purposes.

Comment: People are clicking my ads and my ads are getting viewed, but I am not receiving much per click. My CPC is $0.09, even when I write SEO content it does not budge.

Comment: @user2896120 SEO content tricks are less and less relevant nowadays with more advanced algorithms being made to extract the real content of each site. If your ads are not loading however, then that would really be a cause for concern since users wouldn't even get introduced to the ads. I think that you are correct in trying to debug the issue of load speed in this case, and SEO is probably not the main cause (might even be negligible unless there is a problem with the content of the site)